# Retrieve x in transformation for the edges

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to calculate the x position for the edges (top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right) of a UIView which has currently a CGAffineTransformation active with a rotationAngle. In the picture, I want to calculate the x position of the red circle on the far right side.

This article describes how to do it in Obj-c I believe: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1951182. I tried to convert it to swift 4 but I had to make a lot of changes. I came to this:

```
func offsetPoint(toParentCoordinates aPoint: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: aPoint.x + self.cardView.center.x, y: aPoint.y + self.cardView.center.y)
}

func point(inViewCenterTerms aPoint: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: aPoint.x - self.cardView.center.x, y: aPoint.y - self.cardView.center.y)
}

func point(inTransformedView aPoint: CGPoint, someTransformation: CGAffineTransform) -> CGPoint {
    let offsetItem: CGPoint = point(inViewCenterTerms: aPoint)
    let updatedItem: CGPoint = offsetItem.applying(someTransformation)
    let finalItem: CGPoint = offsetPoint(toParentCoordinates: updatedItem)
    return finalItem
}

func originalFrame(someView: UIView, someTransformation: inout CGAffineTransform) -> CGRect {
    let currentTransform: CGAffineTransform = someTransformation
    someTransformation = CGAffineTransform.identity
    let originalFrame: CGRect = someView.frame
    someTransformation = currentTransform
    return originalFrame
}
```

But I got stuck at the rest. I was wondering if things got any simpler in Swift 4, or on how to continue the rest of the code to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried to use the simple calculation for coordinates: let x = r * sin(angle) and let y = r * cos(angle)?  Where r is the radius, in your case it's a half length of the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed this functionality for one of my own projects as well so I wrote this `UIView` extension based on the Obj-C code by Erica Sadun you've linked to in your question:

```
extension UIView {

    /// Returns the frame without any transformations
    var originalFrame: CGRect {

        let currentTransform = self.transform
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        let frame = self.frame
        self.transform = currentTransform

        return frame
    }

    /// Returns the offset of the given point from the view center
    func centerOffset(from point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: point.x - center.x, y: point.y - center.y)
    }

    /// Returns the point relative to the view center by the given offset
    func pointRelativeToCenter(by offset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: offset.x + center.x, y: offset.y + center.y)
    }

    /// Returns the given point in transformed coordinates
    func newPointInView(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        let offset = self.centerOffset(from: point)
        let transformedOffset = offset.applying(self.transform)

        return self.pointRelativeToCenter(by: transformedOffset)
    }

    // Helpers to get the new View corner coordinates

    var newTopLeft: CGPoint {
        let frame = self.originalFrame
        return self.newPointInView(point: frame.origin)
    }

    var newTopRight: CGPoint {
        let frame = self.originalFrame
        var point = frame.origin
        point.x += frame.size.width
        return self.newPointInView(point: point)
    }

    var newBottomLeft: CGPoint {
        let frame = self.originalFrame
        var point = frame.origin
        point.y += frame.size.height
        return self.newPointInView(point: point)
    }

    var newBottomRight: CGPoint {
        let frame = self.originalFrame
        var point = frame.origin
        point.x += frame.size.width
        point.y += frame.size.height
        return self.newPointInView(point: point)
    }
}
```

Now you can simply access the `newTopLeft`, `newTopRight`, `newBottomLeft` and `newBottomRight` properties on any `UIView` with a `CGAffineTransform` applied, in order to get the respective corner positions of the transformed view in the parent space.

Here's a little Playground example to demonstrate how you can use the extension:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Setting up some example views
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
containerView.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView

let transformedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 200, height: 200))
transformedView.backgroundColor = .clear
transformedView.layer.borderWidth = 3
transformedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
containerView.addSubview(transformedView)

// Add a rotation
let angle = CGFloat.pi / 4
transformedView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -angle)

print(transformedView.newTopLeft) // assuming you've inserted the extension into the Playground somewhere above this line
```

[image]

The `print(transformedView.newTopLeft)` will then output

```
(108.57864376269, 250.0)
```

You can use some simple trigonometry to check that the values are correct.

Comment: Thx bro. Although I had problems with this line: PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView, I tested it in a VC. It worked :). I can award the bounty in a few hours because of restrictions.

Comment: @JasperVisser Oh, right! You need to `import PlaygroundSupport` to make the live view work. I had forgotten to copy that line over.